# Calling js function from the anchor tag href url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search box with search button. When user enters the text in search box and click on search button, it should redirect the url by passing inputed text in search box as an parameter in url.

```
#input tag for search box
<input type="search" placeholder="search" class="search_3">        
<a href="https:.........?searchname=">
    #input tag for search button
    <input type="submit" class="submit_3" value="Search"/>
</a>
```

i have to use the inputed text for searchname parameter in the anchor tag url.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call onlclick your js method and get the search field value and redirect using js code.You can try like this :

```
<input type="search" placeholder="search" class="search_3" id="search_3"> 
   <button name="redirect" onClick="redirecturl()" class="submit_3" value="Search">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function redirecturl()
    { 
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/?searchname="+document.getElementById("search_3").value;

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: That means up-voting while clicking on below there is accept sign.clicking on that means accepting answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to HTML tag things properly, to avoid useless JS.

```
<form method="GET" action="https:...">
<input type="text" name="searchname"/>
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

You can use `form` attribute if the `input` is outside the `form` tag (see HTML living spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-input-element )